# OPEs of vertex operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

Suppose we have two chiral bosons $a(z)$ and $b(z)$ with operator product expansions (OPEs),

$$a(z)a(w) = \log(z-w), \quad b(z)b(w) = -\log(z-w)$$

as well as $a(z)b(w)=0$, including only singular terms. I have little experience with vertex operators, and so I am wondering how one would evaluate an OPE like, for example,

$$e^{a(z)+b(z)} \partial a(w)?$$

(This is from a paper's [free field realization of a VOA](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.07624), section 3.1.) I am assuming normal ordering is implicit, and maybe one approach would be to take a Taylor expansion, that is,

$$:\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}[a(z)+b(z)]^n: \partial a(w)?$$

Am I following the right path and what would one do from here? Are there any useful tricks for dealing with OPEs of vertex operators?